# How to prevent malicious file upload?

Tags: yii2

I have form with file upload, but unfortunately it can upload malicious file like php webshell.

Here is my controller code.

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new TbBank();
        $searchModel = new TbBankSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            //get the instance of the uploaded file
            //return \yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($model);
            $model->bank_code = Html::encode($model->bank_code);
            $model->nama = Html::encode($model->nama);
            $imageName = $model->bank_code;
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            //save the path in the db column
            $path_image = \Yii::$app->params['uploadPath']."bank/";
            $model->logo =  $imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();
            if ($model->file->saveAs($path_image.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension)){
                return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->bank_id]);
            }else{
                \yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($model);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }


    }
```

and here is my TbBank model method rules

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['bank_code', 'nama'], 'required'],
            [['bank_code'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['nama'], 'string', 'max' => 50],        
            [['logo'], 'string', 'max' => 200],  
            [['file'],'file','skipOnEmpty'=>true,'extensions'=>'gif,jpg,jpeg,png','maxSize'=>100*1024*1],
            [['file'],'required','on'=>'create'],
        ];
    }
```

What I need is when user submit, it check uploaded file if contain malicious file it will return error else if file is safe then save file on storage and then record saved.

after some googling looks like yii2 doesn't have built in feature to check malicious file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect the validation rules to work if you are not checking them properly?

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // ...

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        // ...

        // first prepare UploadedFile instance
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');

        // THEN run validation AND IF everything is OK move on
        if ($model->validate()) {

            // VERIFY if save() is successful
            if ($model->save()) {

                // THEN try to save file
                if ($model->file->saveAs($path_image.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension)){
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```